# I want the returned data to be written to the div tag of the html

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
<script>
function showPrice(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("remaining").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("remaining").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getevent.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

The following code returns data to the respective div, but when I see the source code I am unable to find the newly inserted code.

Comment: Why tag it as jQuery when you arent using it?

Comment: How are you viewing your source code? Right Click -> View Source or Using a debug tool like Chromes dev tools?

Comment: If you are using `jQuery`, consider using jquery ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: `view source` in most browsers will never show the changes you've done via JS+dom manipulation. v.s. is basically exactly what you received from the server when the page was first loaded.

Comment: Yes Webnoob , Since I am building a Dynamic form upon the selection of event  and hence code needs to be added . If its not added then I can't submit the data for the php . :( . I am viewing it by Right Clicking and Clicking on View Page source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because it's added dynamically into the dom. Some browsers show the updated html if you right click and inspect the elements (Chrome and firefox). Others are just showing you the begin version of how it's downloaded.

Comment: Hmm I am using firefox but i am unable to see the updated HTML , I am building a dynamic form when an user selects an option then according to the option selected Data needs to be inserted into HTML , In this case its showing visually but code isn't inserted this is causing the dynamically inserted form to fail because no data is being passed when submitted :(

Comment: in chrome or firefox rightclick an element and then you can see it change / current value in it.